# How do I let a user transfer ERC1155 token from my contract address to his address?

Tags: erc-1155

What I want to achieve:
A user should be able to transfer ERC1155 tokens from my contract address to his account.

I've tried two approaches:

1. Deploy ERC1155 contract, then pass its address to the constructor of the second contract which handles transfers.

This works. Users are able to call buyItems() without any errors.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/IERC1155.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/utils/ERC1155Holder.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/presets/ERC1155PresetMinterPauser.sol';

contract ERC1155Preset is ERC1155PresetMinterPauser {
    constructor() ERC1155PresetMinterPauser("https://token-cdn-domain/{id}.json") {}
}

contract testContract is ERC1155Holder {
    IERC1155 private _IERC1155;
    
    constructor(IERC1155 ERC1155Address) {
        _IERC1155 = ERC1155Address;
    }
    
    function buyItems(uint256 _itemId, uint256 _amount) external {
        require(_IERC1155.balanceOf(address(this), _itemId) >= _amount);
        _IERC1155.safeTransferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, _itemId, _amount, "");
    }
}
```

2. Deploy only one contract for ERC1155 and transfers.

This doesn't work. When a user calls buyItems(), I get this error: execution reverted: ERC1155: caller is not owner nor approved

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/utils/ERC1155Holder.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/presets/ERC1155PresetMinterPauser.sol';

contract testContract2 is ERC1155PresetMinterPauser, ERC1155Holder {
    
    constructor() ERC1155PresetMinterPauser("https://token-cdn-domain/{id}.json") {}
    
    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual override(ERC1155PresetMinterPauser, ERC1155Receiver) returns (bool) {
        return interfaceId == type(IERC1155).interfaceId
            || interfaceId == type(IERC1155Receiver).interfaceId
            || super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }
    
    function buyItems(uint256 _itemId, uint256 _amount) external {
        require(balanceOf(address(this), _itemId) >= _amount);
        safeTransferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, _itemId, _amount, "");
    }
}
```

My question: Why does the first approach work, and why not the second one?

Comment: All 3 contracts are deployed by the same address.

Comment: I am having the same problem, have you found any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Could you look into the documentation on openzepplin? I've linked it here, particularly pertaining to [ERC1155PresetMinterPauser](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/presets#ERC1155PresetMinterPauser).There's a dependency that I don't see mentioned here, namely, [Access Control](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/access#AccessControl).

The address you are using, the caller in this case, is not registered as either an `owner` or otherwise `approved`, hence the error.

Comment: Please upvote and chose as answer if this helped!

Comment: But when I transfer using the first method, it works. The 
`_IERC1155.safeTransferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, _itemId, _amount, "");`
shouldn't have worked because the caller wasn't approved there either, but it's working.

Comment: I tried using `ERC1155` and `Ownable` instead of `ERC1155PresetMinterPauser` as well but that didn't work.

Comment: We could get on chat. Could you accept this answer and send me a message. Stack’s comment section isn’t meant for a back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the 2 contract approach works is that the second contract (testContract is ERC1155Holder) does not inherit AccessControl like ERC1155PresetMinterPauser does. Thus, anyone can access testContract.  The single contract approach DOES use AccessControl, so any function included in the ERC1155PresetMinterPauser contract will be restricted.